# How to add two rows in dataframes in a single list and append the resultant row to the other rows in R

Tags: r, list

I am working on financial data, wherein I've read multiple excel sheets into R, each sheet contains financials from different cities.

My requirement is I need to add two "Expenses": labor_cost and medical_cost into one row and append that row to the existing "revenue" row in each dataframe in the list

Sample data:

```
> city1 = data.frame(parameters = c('revenue','labor_cost','medical_cost'), Oct_values = rnorm(3,100), Nov_values = rnorm(3,100))
> city2 = data.frame(parameters = c('revenue','labor_cost','medical_cost'), Oct_values = rnorm(3,100), Nov_values = rnorm(3,100))
> city3 = data.frame(parameters = c('revenue','labor_cost','medical_cost'), Oct_values = rnorm(3,100), Nov_values = rnorm(3,100))
> 
> mylist = list(city1 = city1, city2 = city2, city3 = city3)
> mylist
$city1
    parameters Oct_values Nov_values
1      revenue   100.5933  100.38287
2   labor_cost   101.9234  100.34488
3 medical_cost   101.1133   99.75158

$city2
    parameters Oct_values Nov_values
1      revenue   99.55789   99.78549
2   labor_cost   97.75944   99.18051
3 medical_cost  100.15035   99.34675

$city3
    parameters Oct_values Nov_values
1      revenue  100.85301   97.43272
2   labor_cost   98.87698  100.77948
3 medical_cost  101.24935   99.49057

> 
> mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) { x1 = x[,-1] 
+                                 rownames(x1) = x[,1]
+                                 x1
+                                 })
> 
> mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) { for(i in 1:ncol(x))
+                                       x[[i]] = as.numeric(as.character(x[[i]]))
+                                       x
+                                       } )
> 
> lapply(mylist, function(x) x[2,] + x[3,])
$city1
           Oct_values Nov_values
labor_cost   203.0368   200.0965

$city2
           Oct_values Nov_values
labor_cost   197.9098   198.5273

$city3
           Oct_values Nov_values
labor_cost   200.1263     200.27
```

I need the above result to be appended to the "revenue" row in each dataframe in the list.

Expected output:

```
mylist[[1]]
             Oct_values Nov_values
revenue        100.5933  100.38287
labor_cost     203.0368  200.0965
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` with `cbind` and `rbind`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) cbind(parameter = c('revenue', 'labor_cost'), 
                             rbind(x[1, -1], x[2, -1] + x[3, -1])))


#$city1
#   parameter Oct_values Nov_values
#1    revenue    99.4395    100.071
#2 labor_cost   201.3285    201.844

#$city2
#   parameter Oct_values Nov_values
#1    revenue    100.461    99.5543
#2 labor_cost    198.048   201.5839

#$city3
#   parameter Oct_values Nov_values
#1    revenue    100.401    101.787
#2 labor_cost    199.555    198.531
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
city1 = data.frame(parameters = c('revenue','labor_cost','medical_cost'), 
         Oct_values = rnorm(3,100), Nov_values = rnorm(3,100))
city2 = data.frame(parameters = c('revenue','labor_cost','medical_cost'),
         Oct_values = rnorm(3,100), Nov_values = rnorm(3,100))
city3 = data.frame(parameters = c('revenue','labor_cost','medical_cost'), 
         Oct_values = rnorm(3,100), Nov_values = rnorm(3,100))

mylist = list(city1 = city1, city2 = city2, city3 = city3)
```

Comment: I need to do for 12 months, is there a way I could use a formula for rbind(x[1, -1], x[2, -1] + x[3, -1]) part?

Comment: @KarthikS you mean you have more columns like `Oct_values`, `Nov_values`, `Dec_values` and so on? If that is the case this should still work since it ignores first column (`parameters`) and adds 2nd and 3rd row of all other columns.